# webpack-dev-server: how to preserve state with module.hot.data?

Tags: webpack, web-applications, webpack-dev-server, hot-module-replacement

I'm using webpack-dev-server's Hot Module Replacement (HMR). In the code, I have this:

```js
// index.js

// ...

window.enableFoo = false; // can set this to 'true' in DevTools console

if (module && module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept((err) => {
        console.error('HMR accept() error: ' + err);
    });
    module.hot.addStatusHandler(status => {
        if (status === 'apply') {
            console.log('HMR: update applied');
        }
    });
}
```

I'd like to preserve `window.enableFoo` across HMR update. However, every time the update is applied, `window.enableFoo` goes back to the original value set in the code, which is `true` here.

I read from [HMR's API doc](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement) that I need to use `module.hot.dispose()` and `module.hot.data`, but I couldn't find an example on how to do this, and the doc didn't elaborate. Could someone help me?

([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49595833/how-to-preserve-state-during-hmr-using-angular) is similar, but the code is entangled with Angular and not easy to understand... also, [this thread](https://gitter.im/webpack/webpack?at=5511904f88f1e8da6d306a91) says "If you want to keep state, use dispose and module.hot.data, don't use accept"?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging, this code works. I figure I'd better paste it here in case someone is also looking for an answer.

```
// index.js

// ...

window.enableFoo = false; // can set this to 'true' in DevTools console

if (module && module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept((err) => {
        console.error('HMR accept() error: ' + err);
    });
    module.hot.addStatusHandler(status => {
        if (status === 'apply') {
            console.log('HMR: update applied');
        }
    });

    // added begin ----------------------------------
    module.hot.addDisposeHandler(data => {
        data.enableFoo = window.enableFoo;
    });
    if (module.hot.data) {
        window.enableFoo = module.hot.data.enableFoo;
        console.log('window.enableFoo ' + window.enableFoo);
    }
    // added end ----------------------------------
}
```

Comment: It seems `addDisposeHandler` is only invoked when a *different* module that depends on 'this' module is modified. How do you transfer the state when the hot update is triggered by an edit to a different file?